# Div Extending Beyond Footer

Tags: html, css

i have been working on this layout for quite a while. this is the first time I am working with CSS and HTML. anyway. the problem is that the inner text inside this layout is extending beyond the borders of the "master" div container.

I am attaching all my files in a zip. Please Help me. Otherwise my boss won't let me get on to Javascript. CSS and HTML is really boring.

Thanks in Advance.

File: http://www.mediafire.com/file/9qxrvkmp6hescce/Layout.zip

P.S. No JavaScript Please

Comment: well cant download it. But try looking, if the master div has a fixed height or not?

Comment: I'm afraid the boring HTML and CSS will keep haunting you, even during your Javascript studies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to hide the overflowing content or allow the user to scroll through it within div container.

Specify the overflow property for the div.theAllEncompassingDiv element to either hidden or scroll, respectively.

```
.theAllEncompassingDiv { overflow: hidden; }
```

or

```
.theAllEncompassingDiv { overflow: scroll; }
```

Read more on the overflow property here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: Thanks. This Worked. Though i am not going to apply it on `theAllencompassingDiv` but rather on the div that holds `requestholder`

Comment: You're welcome! Just as another pointer: you may consider using the ID attribute instead of the class attribute to address elements that are unique (e.g. the div.theAllEncompassingDiv).

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm too keen on doing your job for you, but the reason is that you've specified a `max-height` of 408 pixels in your `.theAllEncompassingDiv{}` CSS class.

If you remove that, the `<div>` will become all encompassing once more!

**Edit: Spelling**

Comment: the thing is that this works if it were for a website. but i am going to add a footer to the end if this. Hence the footer has to stick to the bottom of the `theAllEncompassingDiv` and the inner text should not flow beyond the footer and then show up underneath the footer. because that is what happened when I made the footer and gave it `position: absolute;` and `bottom:0`